# ManifoldCF error when creating ElasticSearch output connector

Tags: elasticsearch, manifoldcf

I have ElasticSearch 2.2 running on a linux VM. I'm running ManifoldCF 2.3 on another VM in the same netowrk. Using ManifoldCF's browser UI I added the ElasticSearch output connector and when I save it I get an error in the connector status:

```
Name:   Elastic 
Description:   Elastic search 
Connection type:    ElasticSearch   
Max connections:    10 
Server Location (URL):  http://<IP_ADDRESS>:9200 
Index name: index 
Index type: sharepoint 
Use mapper-attachments: false 
Content field name: contentfield 
Connection status:  ERROR "root_cause":["type":"illegal_argument_exception"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking further in ElasticSearch logs I see the following error:

```
/_status Params: {index=_status}
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No feature for name [_status]
```

A google search for `No feature for name [_status]` led to ES documentation that [states](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/indices-status.html):

> The index _status API has been replaced with the Indices Stats and
>   Indices Recovery APIs.

It looks like manifoldCF's ES connector is not fully compatible with ES v.2

But, I just tested it the connector still works fine, despite the error. So if you see the same issue, just ignore it until ManufoldCF developers fix it.

I filed bug with Apache on this issue: [CONNECTORS-1272](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CONNECTORS-1272)

Comment: Per ManifoldCF developer, this will be fixed in v2.4; also there is patch available, it's attached to the mentioned JIRA ticket

Answer (score 0):

There's a ManifoldCF ticket (CONNECTORS-1272) that has a patch attached; a fix for this problem will be released in MCF 2.4.